# Иерархический путь DB2

Tags: база-данных, db2

Не получается создать запрос в ibm db2 on cloud.
Пробовал сначала с помощью SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH, но говорит мол *An unexpected token "PRIOR"*

```
SELECT ID0, MNAME, SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(MNAME, '/') AS path
FROM MAIN WHERE id0 IN (40,60) CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR id0=main_id;
```

Попробовал сделать так, как делал раньше в SQLite и все работало, но и тут ошибка *Improper use of a string column, host variable, constant, or function "MNAME"*

```
WITH paths (id, path) AS (SELECT id0, Mname FROM main WHERE main_id IS NULL 
UNION SELECT main.id0,  paths.path ||'/'|| main.Mname FROM main inner join paths on main.main_id = paths.id) 
SELECT a.id0, path FROM main AS a INNER JOIN paths AS b ON a.id0 = b.id where a.id0 in (40,60);
```

Помогите, как быть?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вроде как разобрался

```
WITH paths (id, path, counter) AS
(  SELECT id0, Mname, 1 
   FROM main
   WHERE main_id IS NULL 
UNION all
   SELECT id0, path || '/' || Mname, counter + 1
   FROM main, paths
   WHERE main_id = id and counter <=100
) 
SELECT id, path
FROM paths
ORDER BY id
```